# Minimal prime ideal

Tags: ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I was trying the following: Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity, then $R$ has a unique prime ideal if and only if $R$ has a minimal prime ideal which contains all zero-divisors, and all non-units of $R$ are zero divisors.

While proving necessary part, I stuck at the following place: whether the ideal generated by zero divisors, a proper ideal?

While I am unable to give a rigorous proof for sufficient part. Please somebody explain.

Thank you.

Comment: do you want to prove "R has a unique prime ideal then R has a minimal prime ideal which contains all zero divisors"?

Answer (score 1):

The ideal generated by zero divisors is a proper ideal since it has not $1$.

---

If $R$ has a unique prime ideal then:
1- It is unique maximal, *hence have all non-units*;
and
2- It is unique minimal prime, *hence it is the set of nilpotent elements* (which are  zero divisors).

So  all non-units of $R$ are zero divisors.

---

conversely

---

"$R$ has a minimal prime ideal (say $P$) which contains all zero divisors" and since "all non-units of $R$ are zero divisors", $P$ contains all non-units of $R$. Hence $P$ is the unique maximal ideal of $R$. But $P$ is minimal prime. so $R$ has only one prime ideal, namely $P$.

Comment: In the converse part, I agree that the minimal prime ideal is the unique maximal ideal. But how it is the unique prime ideal as there may be some other prime ideal not containing all the zero divisors.

Comment: Sir, P is minimal prime which contains all zero divisors but what I am saying is there may exists a prime ideal which is contained in P but it does not contain all zero divisors. In that case minimality condition of P won't violate.

Comment: the maximal ideal is unique because  it contains all non-units of R. so every (prime) ideal is contained in it.  on the other hand it is minimal. so every  (prime) ideal is contained in a minimal prime. so there is only one prime.

Comment: Sir, I think my definition of minimal prime ideal differs from you. What I have read in Hungerford is: A prime ideal P is said to be minimal prime ideal of an ideal I if there does not exist any prime ideal strictly in between I and P. Also, a definition of minimal ideal is given where I is taken to be the trivial ideal. Now I am confused regarding my question that which ideal are they talking about?

Comment: Your definition of  "minimal prime ideal **of an ideal**" is correct. BUT, definition of "minimal prime ideal **of a ring**", which is in question, is different: it is the "minimal prime ideal **of the ideal $0$"**.